# Insert values into table B based on column from table A?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 tables, a `Users` table and a `User_permissions` table. A user can have many permissions and each permission can be assigned to many different users, although this relationship has not been configured into the database (not my decision!).

Let's say 2 new permissions are created - an `admin` permission and a `superadmin` permission. Furthermore, every user in the `Users` table need to be given this permission by inserting the username and permission name into the `User_permissions` table.

Obviously this could be done manually by `INSERT INTO User_permissions VALUES (userA, admin)` and so on but given that I have a list of over 1,000 users, is there an easier way of doing this? I was thinking of writing a quick script in Java, but is there an easier way using only SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO User_permissions(user, permission)
    SELECT user, 'admin'
    FROM users u;
```