# Incrementing 2 fields after inserting values based on another table?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is an extension of [Insert values into table B based on column from table A?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970599/insert-values-into-table-b-based-on-column-from-table-a)

From the above question, let's say in both the `User_Permissions` and `Users` table there's also 2 more columns recorded for audit purposes: a `version` column and a `transaction_version` column. When inserting the new row (which is based on a row from the `Users` table) into the `User_Permissions` table I need to take the value of the 2 columns in the `Users` table, increment it by 1 and then insert it into the `User_Permissions` table.

Is there an easy SQL query to do this? I suspect it'd have to do with another inline `select` but am unsure of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Triggers after insert](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_insert.php) to perform the needed updates

Comment: I'd prefer not to create triggers or else the dba will start complaining! your link does give me an idea, though. I think you can do a `select into` first and then insert those values in?